# (Rendimiento) Es mejor crear nuevas variables o reasignarlas?

Tags: java, variables, bucles, rendimiento, eficiencia

estoy haciendo un código en java que obtiene datos de una api y los imprime. Hablando específicamente de la manera de tomar las variables, que resulta mas conveniente hablando de rendimiento?

Esta la forma de crear una sola variable e ir reemplazando su valor cada vez que sea necesario.

(favor de ignorar la función que obtiene las variables)

```
        int max = 50000; 
        String variable ="";

        for(int i =0; i < max; i++ ) {

            variable = SpecialFunction.getById("Nombre").toString();
            System.out.println(variable);

            variable = SpecialFunction.getById("Rol").toString();
            System.out.println(variable);

            variable = SpecialFunction.getById("Email").toString();
            System.out.println(variable);

            variable = SpecialFunction.getById("Direccion").toString();
            System.out.println(variable);
        }
```

O es mejor así?
Crear una variable por dato, en cada ciclo, serian miles de variables creadas.

```
        int max = 50000; 

        for(int i =0; i < max; i++ ) {

            String variable = SpecialFunction.getById("Nombre").toString();
            String variable1 = SpecialFunction.getById("Rol").toString();
            String variable2 = SpecialFunction.getById("Email").toString();
            String variable3 = SpecialFunction.getById("Direccion").toString();

            System.out.println(variable + "\n" + variable1 + "\n" + variable2 + "\n" + variable3);

        }
```

la impresión de datos en ambos casos es igual. El ciclo for necesita dar mas de 50000 vueltas con un numero de variables similares a las del ejemplo.

En otros lenguajes serian igual las prioridades de rendimiento? según yo el garbage collector de java ayuda pero no sé cuanto específicamente.

Answer (score 6):

Podrías hacer todo eso sin necesidad de declarar variables:

```
for(int i =0; i < 50_000; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(SpecialFunction.getById("Nombre").toString());
    System.out.println(SpecialFunction.getById("Rol").toString());
    System.out.println(SpecialFunction.getById("Email").toString());
    System.out.println(SpecialFunction.getById("Direccion").toString());
}
```

La programación no solamente consiste en crear programas eficientes, sino también entendibles/mantenibles y cuando abusas de prácticas como el primer ejemplo que pusiste terminas escribiendo código con nombres de variables prácticamente ofuscadas que usas para todo en todas partes y que luego hay que mantener y ni tú ni cualquier otro programador la va a pasar bien.

Con respecto al uso de memoria, una referencia en Java ocupa 4 bytes en sistemas de 32 bits u 8 bytes en sistemas de 64 bits. Si evitas crear 4 referencias por ciclo durante 1 millón de repeticiones por ejemplo, asumiendo que el recolector de basura no haga su trabajo en ese tiempo, terminarás ahorrándote más o menos 8 Megabytes lo cual es casi imperceptible con la cantidad de memoria que tienen los dispositivos hoy en día.

Otra cosa que debes tomar en cuenta es que no hacer una declaración de una variable no significa que te estarás ahorrando el espacio que ocupa el String. El String ya está en memoria, la diferencia es que no lo tendrás referenciado para un posterior uso y por lo tanto se lo llevará el recolector de basura eventualmente.

Si te preocupa tanto el uso de memoria ya sea porque estás trabajando en dispositivos que tienen muy poca, y si necesitaras usar los Strings para otras cosas (además de imprimirlo) podrías hacer un balance entre tus dos ejemplos, es decir declarar las 4 variables afuera del ciclo **poniendo nombres descriptivos** y reutilizarlas. Lo que sí no debes hacer nunca es concatenar Strings con `+` dentro del ciclo porque ahí si estarás ocupando  memoria salvajemente. Los Strings son inmutables y por cada concatenación se crea uno nuevo equivalente a los dos unidos. En esos casos puedes usar un StringBuilder para construirlos.

```
int max = 50000;
String nombre ="";
String rol ="";
String email ="";
String direccion ="";

for(int i =0; i < max; i++ ) {
    nombre = SpecialFunction.getById("Nombre").toString();
    rol = SpecialFunction.getById("Rol").toString();
    email = SpecialFunction.getById("Email").toString();
    direccion = SpecialFunction.getById("Direccion").toString();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(nombre).append("\n").append(rol).append("\n").append(email).append("\n").append(direccion);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

O si quieres puedes sacar del ciclo la creación del StringBuilder y llamar a `sb.setLength(0);` para "limpiarlo" al final de cada iteración.

Comment: Muy interesante tienes algun libro de documentación donde pueda encontrar mas información?